# angularjs 1.6 two way binding of model doesn't update when changed inside a non angular event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### angularjs code

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);   
app.controller('captureCtrl', function () { 
    var vm = this;
    vm.obj = {
        show: false
    };

    addressControls.control.listen('populate', function (address, variations) {
        vm.line1 = address.Line1;
        vm.line2 = address.Line2;
        vm.city = address.City;
        vm.postcode = address.PostalCode;
        vm.obj.show = true;
    });

    vm.test = function () {
        vm.obj.show = true;
    }
});
```

`vm.obj.show` value in the view doesn't get updated when changed inside the 'populate' event, but it does get updated inside vm.test function.  How can I get this to work and why won't binding get updated in the view?  I'm using angularjs 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $scope.apply().

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
      //Your Code here 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 1: I'm sorry--I completely overlooked something. You're using "this" instead of "$scope".

EDIT 2: Since it's a non-angular function, you definitely need a $scope.$apply() in there.

Try doing this instead:

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);   
    app.controller('captureCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.obj = {
            show: false
        };

        addressControls.control.listen('populate', function (address, variations) {

                $scope.line1 = address.Line1;
                $scope.line2 = address.Line2;
                $scope.city = address.City;
                $scope.postcode = address.PostalCode;
                $scope.obj.show = true;
                $scope.$apply();
        });

        $scope.test = function () {
            $scope.obj.show = true;
        };
    });
```

In general, use "$scope" if you want to expose properties for your DOM to work with.

Comment: i got this working without changing the variables to use $scope. 
    $scope.$apply(function(){  vm.line1 = address.Line1;
                vm.line2 = address.Line2;
                vm.city = address.City;
                vm.postcode = address.PostalCode;
                vm.obj.show = true;});

Comment: If you don't care about needing to acces "obj" from your DOM, then sure. But I think code like this is better-suited for a Service (not a Controller).